# Time limited and band limited signal

Tags: communication, signal

How can a time limited signal be of infinite bandwidth and a finite bandwidth signal be of infinite duration?

Comment: ... using the stuff they explained during lecture and recitation ...

Comment: It is generally proven with mathematics.  See Fourier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: what's the Fourier transform of a square pulse... also, something about duality and composition might help

Comment: For intuition, you can imagine a pure tone lasting for eternity. This is one example of a bandlimited signal having infinite duration.